# How to get ListView underneath buttons

Tags: android, textview, alignment, android-linearlayout

Right now my listview is to the right of my last button, but I want it to be underneath all three of my buttons (which are all on the same row). How can I get my listview underneath my buttons?

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".Visualizer"
android:id="@+id/homePage">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_icon"
    android:id="@+id/picButton"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@drawable/cancel_that_pic"
    android:id="@+id/deletePicButton"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:background="@drawable/visual_blueblue"
    android:id="@+id/visIcon"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
   />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp" >
</ListView>

<Space
    android:id="@+id/blank_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried android:orientation="vertical" ??
Can't run your code at this moment since im on the road, sorry.

Comment: I cant see any TextView in your xml code.

Comment: Where is textview in xml file?

Comment: @Paramone I tried that but I need my top three buttons to be aligned side by side, and setting it verticle ruins that :/

Comment: Sorry I meant LIST VIEW.

Comment: Why don't use relative layout. Align your buttons to right and listview to the right of your buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t know if this layout is really what You wanted, because everything is horizontal. I would prefere to set the parent LinearLayout to vertical and then add another LinearLayout. For example:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#000000"
tools:context=".Visualizer"
android:id="@+id/homePage">

<LinearLayout  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#000000">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:background="@drawable/pic_icon"
    android:id="@+id/picButton"
    android:layout_gravity="left"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="top|center"
    android:background="@drawable/cancel_that_pic"
    android:id="@+id/deletePicButton"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="top|right"
    android:background="@drawable/visual_blueblue"
    android:id="@+id/visIcon"
    android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp" >
</ListView>

<Space
    android:id="@+id/blank_space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And, please use the xml attribute "match_parent" instead of "fill_parent". Also, You may will have to do some more stuff here, on some small screens it could happen, that not everything is visible because of Your listView height from 500dp.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This is exactly what I was looking for, all I gotta do now is resize the top three buttons so they fill the empty space and Im set ! :D

Comment: the best way to do is to give android:layout_weight="1" for every ImageButton and set android:scaleType="centerInside" also for every ImageButton...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/homePage"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Visualizer" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/picButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="top|left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/deletePicButton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="top|center" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/visIcon"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:gravity="top|right" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/song_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/blank_space"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Relative LAyout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/appColor"
tools:context="SplashActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLayout">

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```